# SlidingTab with Fragment startActivityForResult doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult

Thank in advance for the time you pass on my problem.

I have 2 Activities :

Activity A and Activity B.

The Activity A call Activity B.

The Activity B is an activity for Sliding Tab (5 fragments are on the Sliding Tab module).

On one of the fragment, i use startActivityForResult()

```
intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), Research.class);
intent.putExtra("Type", temp_type);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundleapp);
intent.putExtra("position", position);

getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

I also tried :

```
intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), Research.class);
intent.putExtra("Type", temp_type);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundleapp);
intent.putExtra("position", position);

startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

The first part work because i was redirected on the Research Activity.

On the Research Activity i call

```
compteur = 0;
Intent data = new Intent();
Bundle bundletest = new Bundle();
bundletest.putSerializable("Object", ObjectTest);
data.putExtras(bundletest);
Log.e("DEBUG", data.toString());
setResult(15, data);
super.finish();
```

It is here that i have a problem.

The method `super.finish()` doesn't call onActivityResult() on Activity B

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.e("DEBUG","ici");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String temp_path = "none";
    String temp_name_file = "none";

    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

I have a also a method called onActivityResult on my Fragment but not called either.

Someone can help me ???

Sincerly,

**Edit** :

The problem :

I start The Activity B from The Activity A. In the Activity B i have a SlidingTabLayout (same as Google IO code 2014). On one of the 5 fragment i used i call startActivityForResult() ===> Activity C.

In Activity C ==> I call finish() or super.finish(). After that, i come back to Activity A ===> First misunderstanding. (Why Activity A) 
===> Second, No Called OnActivityResult() done ....

Maybe my app Crash ??? But i don't see anything on the logcat

Thank Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `startActivityForResult` will trigger `onActivityResult` in the activity that started it, so in this case Activity A would receive the call to `onActivityResult`.  Additionally, when using `startActivityForResult`, you should set a result code by calling `setResult` before calling `finish`, to help you distinguish between different result states (i.e. success vs failure).

Comment: I called onActivityResult on the activity A and B. I also used setResult just before super.finish().

Answer (score 1):

I forgot something.  After calling `finish`
 method, I come back  in activity A like  nothing happend.

Comment: instead of super.finish() try removing the super and calling just the  finish() method.; super.finish may call your base activity to finish but not your child activity.